# Ansible doesn't connect to server - Connection timed out

Tags: ansible

I try connect to server using ansible. I have installed ubuntu server with openssh. I add public key on server and when I try connect to server using ssh it works:

```
ssh ubuntu@92.168.0.14
```

So I create ansible inventory file `hosts`

```
[dbservers]
192.16.0.14 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```

And next I try run command:

```
ansible all -i hosts -m ping -vvvv
```

But when I run it i get an error:

```
<192.16.0.14> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
<192.16.0.14> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<192.16.0.14> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-vvv', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/home/karol/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'Port=22', '-o', 'IdentityFile=/home/karol/.ssh/id_rsa', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=ubuntu', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '192.16.0.14', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1431369235.84-48071922815331 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1431369235.84-48071922815331 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1431369235.84-48071922815331'"]
192.16.0.14 | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/home/karol/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-192.16.0.14-22-ubuntu" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.16.0.14 [192.16.0.14] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect to address 192.16.0.14 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 192.16.0.14 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I use the same identity file so why ansible can't connect to server?

Comment: your manual ssh line is for `92.168.xx.yy`, while the Ansible line is for `192.68.xx.yy`.

Comment: And you alse have some `192.16.0.14`. May be you want to sort out `192.16.0.14` vs. `92.168.0.14` vs. `192.168.0.14` first ?

Comment: tedder42 - you're right. It was my mistake. I search problem in wrong place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the trouble is here:

```
ubuntu@**92.168.0.14**

[dbservers]
**192.16**.0.14 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```

Here is different ip-addresses with different fors octets:
92.168 and 192.16